# Why fopen fails on Nexus5x android device ( C++ )

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to save a bmp into file in my C++ android app (I am working with chromium project).

```
FILE* fp = fopen("/myimage.bmp", "wb"); // result: fp==NULL, errno==30

FILE* fp = fopen("/Pictures/myimage.bmp", "wb"); // result: fp==NULL, errno==2
```

Phone is Nexus 5x having no sdcard. `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` are set.

Looks like I am using invalid path? Which path would be valid? It is a debug output, so I need any path that would work.

Comment: You cannot write to `/` on any Linux-based system without superuser-level privileges. "I am working with chromium project" -- then figure out where Chromium writes files, and write your files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're accessing your internal storage of your application then the root path of your application storage is

```
String ROOT_PATH = "/data/data/" + "com.your.package.name" + "/";
```

So in case of accessing your file from your internal storage you have to declare the file path like this.

```
FILE* fp = fopen(ROOT_PATH + "myimage.bmp", "wb");
```

But this doesn't ensure your problem to be solved as @CommonsWare suggested,

> "the root path of your application storage is" -- the path varies by
>   OS version, user account (primary vs. secondary), and possibly device
>   manufacturer. NEVER HARDCODE PATHS. If NDK code needs to write to a
>   location, Java code should be passing in the path, where that is
>   derived from a method (e.g., getFilesDir()).

So I'm referring to his comment again in your question.

> You cannot write to / on any Linux-based system without
>   superuser-level privileges. "I am working with chromium project" --
>   then figure out where Chromium writes files, and write your files
>   there.

These are some valuable insights suggested by @CommonsWare which might help you. Thanks.

Comment: "the root path of your application storage is" -- the path varies by OS version, user account (primary vs. secondary), and possibly device manufacturer. NEVER HARDCODE PATHS. If NDK code needs to write to a location, Java code should be passing in the path, where that is derived from a method (e.g., `getFilesDir()`).

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot for your kind comment. I'm removing my answer as its not recommended. Thanks again.

Comment: Your point regarding writing to the incorrect location is a good one. And, for lightweight debugging purposes, your hardcoded value may work. I just worry that developers will infer that they can use that "for realz" and have it work across devices.

Comment: But I don't have access to Java layer and  I need  simpliest C++ solution to write a file somewhere for debugging purposes

Comment: I undestand now. I'm editing my answer as per your valuable insight. Thanks again.